# Javascript code on link click runs only once, I want to get it run everytime when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have designed a template, and i am giving options to users, to change style of div, they have 5 different options to choose from, each style is associated with each class name, so when ever a user clicks a link it will change the div style. So, I changed the class name of div with javascript code:

```
function changeClass(value){

        style = [ 'view view-first', 'view view-second', 'view view-third', 'view view-fourth', 'view view-fifth' ];
         var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
         for(var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {

            // PERFORM STUFF ON THE ELEMENT
            elements[i].className = style[value];

            // elements[i] no longer exists past this point, in most browsers
        }   
        }
```

1st I collected class name of divs i want to change and stored it in an array,

2nd I created a new array with new class name.

3rd I ran a loop and assigned new class name to divs.

4th I incorporated onClick changeClass(0) changeClass(1) etc event on links and ran the function.

The following code is ok, when i click the link for the 1st time, when i click another link with onClick event, the style dosent change. In particular class name change is only happening when i click on any of the links for the 1st time in the page.

My objective is to change style of divs according to the associated link.

Comment: you change your classes 1st time, and whan you click 2nd time - thay are already setted, what are you waiting for?

Comment: basically, there are 5 links and all 5 links are associated with 5 different class name which change the style of the div, so each link have onClick event like changeClass(0) changeClass(1) etc

Comment: I have designed a template, and i am giving options to users, to change style of div, they have 5 different options to choose form, each style is associated with each class name, so when ever a user clicks a link it will change the div style.. This is my intention.

Comment: Also if you are using [tag:jQuery] (*as you have tagged the question*) you can simplify the code quite a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only works the first time because you are searching for elements with the `test` class.  Then you replace the class with the ones from the function. So there are no elements with `test` class after the first run, and subsequently nothing is found on the following runs.

Workaround (*is to keep the `test` class, but use it only for selecting and not for styling*)

```js
    var style = ['view view-first', 'view view-second', 'view view-third', 'view view-fourth', 'view view-fifth'];

    function changeClass(value) {

      var targetClass = "test",
          elements = document.getElementsByClassName( targetClass );
      
      for (var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        // PERFORM STUFF ON THE ELEMENT
        elements[i].className = targetClass + ' ' +  style[value];

        // elements[i] no longer exists past this point, in most browsers
      }
    }
```

```css
.view-first{color:red;}
.view-second{color:blue;}
.view-third{color:green;}
.view-fourth{color:yellow;}
.view-fifth{color:orange;}
```

```html
<div class="test">Test #1</div>
<p> irrelevant text </p>
<div class="test">Test #2</div>
<p> irrelevant text </p>
<p> irrelevant text </p>
<div class="test">Test #3</div>
<div class="test">Test #4</div>
<div class="test">Test #5</div>
<p> irrelevant text </p>
<p> irrelevant text </p>
<p> irrelevant text </p>
<div class="test">Test #6</div>
<div class="test">Test #7</div>

<button onclick="changeClass(0);">first (red)</button>
<button onclick="changeClass(1);">second (blue)</button>
<button onclick="changeClass(2);">third (green)</button>
<button onclick="changeClass(3);">fourth (yellow)</button>
<button onclick="changeClass(4);">fifth (orange)</button>
```

---

An alternative with jQuery

```
var style = ['view view-first', 'view view-second', 'view view-third', 'view view-fourth', 'view view-fifth'];

function changeClass(value) {
    $('.test').removeClass().addClass( style[value] ).addClass( 'test' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're obliterating all the classes on your queried elements when you execute `elements[i].className = style[value];` so `document.getElementsByClassName("test")` won't match anything on subsequent invocations.

It's not exactly clear what your intentions are, but if you just want to add to your class list, replace `elements[i].className = style[value];` with `elements[i].className += style[value];`

Comment: understood, where i was lagging sir, but there is a problem with your solution, eachtime when the different links are clicked, it attached new class name in the tag <div id="test" class="test viewview view-firstview view-secondview view-third"> like this.. it should get replaced.

Comment: I have designed a template, and i am giving options to users, to change style of div, they have 5 different options to choose form, each style is associated with each class name, so when ever a user clicks a link it will change the div style.. This is my intention.

Comment: So then you need to parse your template classes out of your elements' `class` attribute so you can retain any other classes. Easiest way is using [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), but be wary of the browser support.

Comment: browser compatibility is going to be first priority. I am trying to use your suggestion, just need a advice, how about, using >test< class in all my stored class name, so if a link is clicked, it will retain test class.

Answer (score 0):

After the initial call to changeClass, there would no longer be any Classnames of "test".

```
 elements[i].className = style[value];
```

Is changing the className "test" to whatever index of style is specified in the function call.

It therefore cannot find the class name "test" after the initial call to do anything.  You would have to refresh the page or call a different function to change the classnames back to "test".

You might want to declare IDs of "test1", "test2", "test3" and so forth.

Then you can call (if the elements are inputs):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if(inputs[i].id.indexOf("test") >= 0)
    inputs[i].className = style[value]
}
```